# how to declare the possible values of an attribute in java

Tags: java, enumerated-types

My class must have an attribute of type string which can have just four values :

```
value1, value2, value3, or value4 ;
```

How it can be done in java ?

Comment: you can use switch case for that... or can apply if condition while taking that input

Comment: Coding it usually does the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [enumerated types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html), for example

```
public enum MyStringType {
  value1{
      public String toString() {
          return "this is value1";
      }
  },

  value2{
      public String toString() {
          return "this is value2";
      }
  }
 /* etc etc */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done a few different ways. This is the most direct (and probably ugly) way to do it, because you only have four eventualities.

```
 private String someString;

  public void setSomeString(String inString){
     if(inString.equals("valueOne") || 
        inString.equals("valueTwo") || 
        inString.equals("valueThree")||
        inString.equals("valueFour"){

        someString = inString;

 }else{

     //handle this here

   }
```